# PIE.htc not working with YUI3 in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, yui3

I'm using PIE for shadows, radius borders and gradients but none of these are working in IE8.

Here is an example of the code I'm using for radius and shadow.

.conflict-suggestion-body-left{

```
border-right:2px solid #FDFDFD;
border-bottom:2px solid #FDFDFD; 
border-top:1px solid #B8B8B8;
float: left;
width: 49%;
margin-left:1px;
-moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
-webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #000;
border-radius:0 0 2px 2px;
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
```

}

Here is an example of the code I'm using for the gradient.

.yui3-widget-hd {

```
background: #C9D2DD;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#D8D8DA', endColorstr='#B6CAD5');    
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#D8D8DA), to(#B6CAD5));
background: -moz-linear-gradient(0% 100% 90deg, #B6CAD5 35%, #D8D8DA 83%, white 100%) repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border: 1px solid #F3FAFE;
border-radius: 0.435em 0.435em 0 0;
behavior: url(PIE.htc);
height: 33px;
margin: 0;
width: 97%;
cursor: default;
```

}

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the behavior url as absolute path:

http://css3pie.com/documentation/known-issues/#relative-paths

Maybe this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think its your url problem.. try this one

```
behavior: url(//Yoursite.com/path/to/PIE.htc);
```